# How to call a method after digest finish

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to call a method which restore a focus to html element after a page is refreshed (ajax call). However I am getting *$digest is in progress error*.  How can I call make method after $digest has finished ?

Answer (score 0):

DIRTY HACK, but...

```
$rootScope.$$postDigest(function() {
  elem.focus();
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answer?